# Cannot get data to display correctly on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a school project where I am pulling data from an API and creating a "trading card" that has info on both sides. For some reason I can only get the photo's to show up on each card, the text from the data is huge and doesn't align with the correct card.  I am expecting to get the H1, H3 and P tags to show the correct data and fit normally on each card.

```js
async function getAPIData(url) {

    try {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json()
        return data

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
//now use the returned async data
const theData = getAPIData('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/teams')
.then(data => {
    for (const team of data.data) {
        populateDOM(team)
    }
})

let mainArea = document.querySelector('main')
function populateDOM(team) {

        let teamScene = document.createElement('div')
        let teamCard = document.createElement('div')    
        let teamFront = document.createElement('div')
        let teamBack = document.createElement('div')
        let name = document.createElement('h1')
        let conference = document.createElement('p')
        let division = document.createElement('p')
        let pic = document.createElement('img')

        fillCardBack(teamBack, team)

        teamScene.setAttribute('class', 'scene')
        teamCard.setAttribute('class', 'card')
        teamFront.setAttribute('class', 'card__face card__face--front')
        teamBack.setAttribute('class', 'card__face card__face--back')
        pic.setAttribute('class', 'picDivs')


        name.textContent = team.full_name
        pic.src = `../images/${team.id}.png`
        conference.textContent = team.conference
        division.textContent = team.division

        teamFront.appendChild(pic)  
        teamFront.appendChild(name)
        
        teamCard.appendChild(teamFront)
        teamCard.appendChild(teamBack)
        teamScene.appendChild(teamCard)

        mainArea.appendChild(teamScene)

        teamCard.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            teamCard.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
          });
    
}
function fillCardBack(teamBack, data){
    let teamAbbreviation = document.createElement('p')
    teamAbbreviation.textContent = data.abbreviation
    teamBack.appendChild(teamAbbreviation)

    let conference = document.createElement('p')
    conference.textContent = data.conference
    teamBack.appendChild(conference)

    let division = document.createElement('p')
    division.textContent = data.division
    teamBack.appendChild(division)
}
```

```css
main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;

}
.picDivs{
    width: 50%;
}

.charDivs{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.scene {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 40px 0;
    perspective: 600px;
  }
  
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .card.is-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  .card__face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 260px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .card__face--front {
    /* background: white; */
  }
  
  .card__face--back {
    /* background: blue; */
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <main>

    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The text is styled to be white, so you can't see the `<h1>` contents against the white background.

Comment: @Pointy I cannot believe I did not catch that. Thank you. I need to edit my question a bit because I cannot get the contents to fit on the correct card

Comment: There's no need to post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. You can just insert your code into a "code snippet" in your question by clicking the `<>` button.

Comment: The team names are huge because you've got `font-size: 40px`